# Why does 2.11.1 fail with error: not found: type Application?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
object Main extends Application{
  println("Hello World");
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/xx/JavaProjects/ScalaApplication1/src/scalaapplication1/Main.scala:8: error: not found: type Application
object Main extends Application{
                    ^
one error found
```

I'm using Scala 2.11.1.

Comment: It works for me (scala 2.10.4), but note that `Application` has been deprecated from scala 2.9, use `App` instead.

Comment: Great. @EndeNeu , `App` works for me (v 2.11.1) .. Write that as an answer please.

Comment: App works for Scala version 2.11.7

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Application` has been deprecated from scala 2.9, probably it has been deleted in scala 2.11 (it still exists in scala 2.10) even though at the moment I can't find proofs for that, use `App` instead.

Proof found, [this is the scala 2.11 branch on github](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.11.x/src/library/scala) which has only an `App.scala` and [this is the 2.10](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.10.x/src/library/scala) which has `App.scala` and `Application.scala` with a deprecated warning.

Answer (score 13):

You need to extends the App trait, the Application trait doesn't exists.
How i've done compile:

```
object Main extends App{
     println("Hello World");
 }
```